# Java percent of number

Tags: java

Is there any way to calculate (for example) 50% of 120?
I tried:

```
int k = (int)(120 / 100)*50;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You're integer dividing 120 by 100, which is 1. You'll need to multiply by 50 first, then divide, or use floats.

Comment: Yes, Java is capable of basic math.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
int k = (int)(120 / 100)*50;
```

The above does not work because you are performing an 
integer division expression (120 / 100) which result is
integer 1, and then multiplying that result to 50, giving 
the final result of 50.

If you want to calculate 50% of 120, use:

```
int k = (int)(120*(50.0f/100.0f));
```

more generally:

```
int k = (int)(value*(percentage/100.0f));
```

Comment: Or, you know, `120/2`.

Answer (score 5):

```
int k = (int)(120*50.0/100.0);
```

Comment: why complicate? inner parenthesis is not actually required.

Answer (score 4):

Never use floating point primitive types if you want exact numbers and consistent results, instead use BigDecimal.

The problem with your code is that result of (120/100) is 1, since 120/100=1.2 in reality, but as per java, int/int is always an int.
To solve your question for now, cast either value to a float or double and cast result back to int.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using BigDecimal, rather than float or double. Division by 100 is always exact in BigDecimal, but can cause rounding error in float or double.

That means that, for example, using BigDecimal 50% of x plus 30% of x plus 20% of x will always sum to exactly x.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple as 2 * 2 = 4 :)

```
int k = (int)(50 * 120) / 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

Division must be float, not int

(120f * 50 / 100f)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need floating point in this case you can write

```
int i = 120 * 50 / 100;
```

or

```
int i = 120 / 2;
```